# Unknown column in on clause on a multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get pairs of matching columns by joining the table Customer with the already joined table of BuyVehicle & Vehicle which I've given the alias 't'. How is p1.SSN and I assume p2.SSN will follow an unknown column if I've assigned the alias in the first line?

```
SELECT p1.SSN, p2.SSN FROM Customer AS p1, Customer AS p2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT BVSSN, BVVin, Vin FROM CarPurchase INNER JOIN Car ON BVVin = Vin) 
AS t ON p1.SSN = BVSSN & p2.SSN = BVSSN
WHERE p1.SSN < p2.SSN AND //matching columns comparisons yet to be added;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p1.SSN' in 'on clause'

Comment: 1. You haven't assigned anything. If mysql says there is no such column - then there is no such column 2. `&` is not what you think - you need to use `AND`

Comment: I've fixed those issues but I still receive column p1.SSN error when Customer table has SSN column.

Comment: If mysql says there is no such column - then there is no such column

Comment: mysql> DESCRIBE Customer;
| SSN     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

Comment: there is a chance you're querying wrong database or server

Comment: That would be false. Only database I'm using is the one I specified with 'use db1;'. The only database I created in MYSQL.

Comment: well, there is no anything magic with mysql. If it says there is no such column - then there is no. I recommend you to check everything twice and reduce your query to smallest possible that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I know that which is why I came here for help. 'mysql> SELECT  p1.SSN FROM Customer AS p1 WHERE p1.SSN = 1;
1 row in set (0.29 sec)
Is that enough proof for you that the column exists?

Comment: continue making the query as complex as in the question, step by step. And check when it's broken. Add nested query at first, then add another join, etc

Comment: I've done that which is why I'm even here posting this question.... If you aren't going to help please stop responding. I don't want to turn this into a discussion.

Comment: well - it's still **your** issue. If you don't want to debug your own buggy query - we cannot help. Just because you haven't provided sensitive information. The thing is - if mysql returns there is no such column - then there is no. You could continue arguing or start debugging the query following the advice I've given earlier.

Comment: Of course it's my problem I've been debugging for the last hour. I've already proven to you that the column exist in Customer by not only using DESCRIBE but a simple query. The reason people post questions is because they are in need help or can't debug further. I don't need you telling me to debug my query when I've tried hence this post.

Comment: I already proposed you to make your query complex *step by step*, checking the result after each modification. That is called debugging. If you do that - then you'll know for sure what causes the issue. Just take the smallest working query and make it more complex step by step. After that share the results in the question

Comment: You also swore I was accessing a different database or server. My query was created step by step. The join of Car and Car Purchases returns exactly what I want and my attempt of joining that with Customer table on the column SSN is failing which is why I'm here for help. There isn't anything to check if the second step fails.

Comment: 1. I didn't swear. I told there is a chance 2. if you join by another columns - does the query fails as well?

Comment: Yes. Unknown column 'p1.name'.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. Please refresh the query in the question to the exact query that throws the error. And the exact error message.

Comment: It's acting as if my alias was never assigned. Because when I just do 'AS t ON SSN = BVSSN' it works;

Comment: well, it looks very unreal actually :-S `FROM Customer` p1` --- what if you don't use `AS`? Do you execute the query right in mysql console?

Comment: Same error. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the mixing of the different types of joins.  MySQL does not recognize the p1 table, because it is not part of the "joins".  The following should fix this:

```
SELECT p1.SSN, p2.SSN
FROM Customer AS p1 cross join
     Customer AS p2 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT BVSSN, BVVin, Vin
      FROM CarPurchase INNER JOIN
           Car
           ON BVVin = Vin
    ) AS t
    ON p1.SSN = BVSSN and p2.SSN = BVSSN
WHERE p1.SSN < p2.SSN AND //matching columns comparisons yet to be added;
```

Actually, you should just move the `WHERE` clause into an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p1.SSN, p2.SSN
FROM Customer AS p1 join
     Customer AS p2 
     on  p1.SSN < p2.SS INNER JOIN
     (SELECT BVSSN, BVVin, Vin
      FROM CarPurchase INNER JOIN
           Car
           ON BVVin = Vin
    ) AS t
    ON p1.SSN = BVSSN and p2.SSN = BVSSN
```

Comment: Thank you! This was seriously bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

1. what is & -- there is no SQL like that.. change to AND
2. this is incorrect
   SELECT BVSSN, BVVin, Vin FROM CarPurchase INNER JOIN Car ON BVVin = Vin

   SELECT CarPurchase.BVSSN, Car.BVVin, Car.Vin FROM CarPurchase INNER JOIN Car ON CarPurchase.BVVin = Car.Vin

else use alises

Comment: Good catch on the & but I didn't add the 'table'.column because each table has unique column names. But the error column p1.SSN is still an issue.